# how to pass a user name(including Chinese Character) from dialog inputs through regular express?

Tags: watson-conversation

We'd like to process the following scenario
1. user: "Hi"
2. Watson answers: Hi, what's your name?
3. user:"Joe楊"
4. Watson answers : Hi, Joe楊, welcome to Watson

Comment: attached please find our attempts, it works for numbers, we don't know how to do it with any characters(including Chinese Character), Thanks  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3n0L-fAmNEXdmNjLVdxRElxZjQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog node would be as shown below:

[image]

[image]

When input text matches regular expression, it stores the input text to context variable $username ( as shown above)

Output:

[image]

Comment: this works for both Chinese and English: input.text.matches('^[\u4e00-\u9fa5_a-zA-Z0-9]+$')